# Apache Nifi with Kafka | request time out ms | No Response or Output from Kafka to Nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have server with Apache Nifi as well as another server with Kafka.
and I am trying to consume messages from Kafka via Nifi. and neither gives me errors or anything.

It is like somehow freezing or nothing it happens.In addition, between two server it is PING and telnet correctly perfectly with 9092 and 2181
[image]

Comment: did you see messages with kafka-console-consumer ? share your processor configuration. look at nifi-app.log ...

Comment: You shouldn't need Nifi to reach Kafka's Zookeeper. Have you tried the other consume kafka processors? Do you have to define the entire flow? Looks like not even the consumer is working. Does Nifi work if you just read a file locally? Any error **logs** in the CLI or files? Does kafka console consumer work on the CLI? What debugging have you really done?